# CSES standard solution for range query problem giving TLE

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

Problem statement is from [CSES](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1646/)

This is a standard question where we are given a list of numbers and a number of queries. For each query, you have to give the sum of numbers in the given range.

My implementation in python:

```
def solve():
    n,q = [int(a) for a in input().split(' ')]
    arr = [int(a) for a in input().split(' ')]
 
    cumulativeArray = [0] # Initial entry added to make 1 based indexing
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        sum += arr[i]
        cumulativeArray.append(sum)
 
    for i in range(q):
        x,y = [int(a) for a in input().split(' ')]
        print(cumulativeArray[y] - cumulativeArray[x-1])
 
solve()
```

This gives the required answers correctly for all my custom test cases. But gives TLE for huge test cases.

I believe this is happening due to `split()` method in my code.
Any leads are welcome.

Comment: Instead of building `cumulativeArray` manually, consider `np.cumsum` or `itertools.accumulate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add on to @hjpotter92's answer:

- If you're not using `i` in `for i in range(q)`, replace it with `_`, i.e. `for _ in range(q)` to indicate that you are not using the variable.
- It turns out the actual bottleneck is the many calls to `print()` in a for loop. If you tweak your code so it instead builds a string of all the answers to the queries in memory and prints it out in one go, it will pass all the test cases. I verified this by submitting the code below.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

n, q = map(int, input().split())
arr = map(int, input().split())

cumulative_sums = [0]
current_sum = 0
for num in arr:
    current_sum += num
    cumulative_sums.append(current_sum)

queries = (tuple(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(q))
print(
    "\n".join(
        f"{cumulative_sums[b] - cumulative_sums[a - 1]}" for a, b in queries
    )
)
```

Comment: Nice catch!! We all missed this.

Comment: Ah yes! Buffer cleanups.

Answer (score 5):

You are already using the optimal solution algorithm for the problem. A few things, which might speed-up the computations (`.split` should not be the limiting factor in most likeliness)

### Variable naming

Use names which match the problem description, so that it becomes easier to follow your code. So, instead of `x, y` it'd be `a, b`. Also, in python, it is a good practice to name your variables in `lower_snake_case`.

`sum` is an builtin function. Do not override this.

### Computing `len`

You do not need to iterate over indices as the index is not really being used anyway. Lists can be iterated over their values itself.

### Lazy iterators

Instead of generating list inline, you can use generators so that the values are yielded when iterating, and not consuming memory.

### `.split`

Not passing a parameter to `.split` is same as providing whitespace as parameter.

---

Rewrite:

```
def solve():
    n, q = map(int, input().split())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
 
    cumulative_summation = [0]
    running_sum = 0
    # Not calculating `len` of `arr`, also, you don't need to calculate it.
    # the length is known to be `n`.
    for value in arr:
        running_sum += value
        cumulative_summation.append(running_sum)
 
    for i in range(q):
        a, b = map(int, input().split())
        print(cumulative_summation[b] - cumulative_summation[a - 1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the recommendations.
Unfortunately, it's still giving TLE. 
The reason I suspect `split` to be time-consuming is the fact that initially a string is read and split into n elements. Other languages like java/C++ have an option to read individual numbers directly.

Comment: Additionally, I used `stdin` to speed up reading. But that didn't help either.

Comment: Update: I've added stdout for outputting and converting the same array in place to cumulative sum. Still TLE.

Comment: You can do a performance check to get which operation is consuming the most time. Most likely cause could be the `.append` operation @AdityaGupta

Comment: I disagree with the move to `map`. I think the OP's input method is fine, though he should be using a generator and not a list for those lines. The generator is much clearer to read.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @hjpotter92. I'll do performance check when I get some free cycles. Will get back to you guys shortly.

Comment: @Reinderien I will do performance evaluation and comment further

Comment: How would that "breaks on empty input" look like, exactly?

Comment: @HeapOverflow `while line := input():`

Comment: @hjpotter92 But how do you handle the `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` caused by that?

Comment: @HeapOverflow ah, you're correct. Although, as mentioned in reply above, with a while loop `while True: line = input(); if not input: break`

Comment: @hjpotter92 That gives the same error.

Comment: @HeapOverflow the first suggested implementation works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNg8X.png

Comment: @hjpotter92 You additionally entered an empty line, didn't you? That's not guaranteed to exist in the input, and in fact there isn't one. If you submit it with that way, you'll get that error.

Comment: I see your edit. It has nothing to do with being piped. It's solely about whether there's an empty line. If what you pipe in has an empty line, that works. If you enter manually and end the input (probably you can do that by pressing ctrl-d) without an empty line, then you get the error.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I think the automated evaluators do use stdin redirection pipes to feed input data (dockerised run of code).

Comment: I think so, too. But how is that relevant?

Comment: @HeapOverflow that is what i was thinking when i put in that edit above. hadn't tested with the same though. will remove the entire section now.

Answer (score 3):

**Your solution is alright and I got it accepted as-is. Just had to choose "PyPy3" instead of "CPython3".**

Anyway...

I'd use `accumulate` and a helper function to reduce code duplication and make the interesting code clearer:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def input_ints():
    return map(int, input().split())

def solve():
    _, q = input_ints()
    cumulative = [0, *accumulate(input_ints())]
    
    for _ in range(q):
        a, b = input_ints()
        print(cumulative[b] - cumulative[a - 1])

solve()
```

This still gets TLE with CPython3, though, and gets accepted in PyPy3 in the same 0.81 seconds as yours.

As @setris [pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251125/219610) you can get it accepted by using a single `print`. Here's my version of that, not mixing the calculations with the printing, which I find clearer. Got accepted with CPython3 in 0.69 seconds.

```
from itertools import accumulate

def input_ints():
    return map(int, input().split())

def solve():
    _, q = input_ints()
    cumulative = [0, *accumulate(input_ints())]

    results = []
    for _ in range(q):
        a, b = input_ints()
        results.append(cumulative[b] - cumulative[a - 1])

    print('\n'.join(map(str, results)))

solve()
```

If you don't mind the asymmetry of `solve` reading the input itself but not printing the output itself, you could also make it a generator:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def input_ints():
    return map(int, input().split())

def solve():
    _, q = input_ints()
    cumulative = [0, *accumulate(input_ints())]

    for _ in range(q):
        a, b = input_ints()
        yield cumulative[b] - cumulative[a - 1]

print('\n'.join(map(str, solve())))
```

I *do* mind that asymmetry, though. Another symmetric way, instead of `solve` doing both input and output, would be to `solve` doing *neither of them*:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def input_ints():
    return map(int, input().split())

def solve(x, queries):
    cumulative = [0, *accumulate(x)]

    for a, b in queries:
        yield cumulative[b] - cumulative[a - 1]

_, q = input_ints()
x = input_ints()
queries = (input_ints() for _ in range(q))
results = solve(x, queries)
print('\n'.join(map(str, results)))
```

Granted, now the "main block" doesn't look nice. But `solve` is now very nice, and it can also be tested nicely by just calling it with data, for example:

```
>>> list(solve([3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 5, 3],
               [[2, 4], [5, 6], [1, 8], [3, 3]]))
[11, 2, 24, 4]
```